# Why can't I run RubyGame?

Tags: ruby, macos, installation, rubygame

I followed the instructions from the [RubyGame wiki](https://github.com/rubygame/rubygame/wiki/Mac-Install-Guide). Everything worked up until I tried to run the application:

```
ruby a_rubygame_app.rb

# => ruby: No such file or directory -- a_rubygame_app.rb (LoadError)
```

What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a_rubygame_app.rb` is not the actual name of any file... In the install docs, they've used a common programmer technique of naming a file with something that should look like it needs to be replaced.

This is often done with things like `/path/to/yourfile` – which is not a path to any actual file on your computer, but is meant to be replaced with an actual path and filename – or `obj.my_method`, which is meant to indicate that you call a method you've created by replacing `my_method` with the actual method name.

According to the rubygame README,

```
We also recommend that you take a peek at the demo applications in
the 'samples' directory, especially image_viewer.rb,
demo_rubygame.rb, and chimp.rb.
```

Try to find your way into the `samples` directory, and then try running `ruby image_viewer.rb`, `ruby demo_rubygame.rb` or `ruby chimp.rb`.